# Using a mixture of QuadElement and TriangleElement in ElementMesh

Tags: mesh

#### TL;DR

Is it possible to have a `ElementMesh` made of a mixture of a ``` TriangleElements`` and ``` QuadElements`

#### Setup

I've got the following sort of grid:

```
baseGrid =
  CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {.1, .1}];
myGrid =
  MapIndexed[
   If[EvenQ[#2[[1]]], 
     Append[
      # - ConstantArray[{0, .05}, Length[#]], 
      #[[-1]] + {0, .05}
      ], 
     #
     ] &,
   baseGrid
   ] ;

Point[Flatten[myGrid, 1]] // Graphics
```

[image]

I then have a function defined over this grid (as in I have a function value at each point). I'd then like to turn this thing into an `ElementMesh`.

I'd like to turn it into a `ElementMesh` in a special kind of way:

```
getRectMesh[grid_] :=
  Module[
   {
    dims = Length /@ grid, inds, els,
    quads,
    tris
    },
   inds = getRectMeshInds[dims];
   tris =
    Pick[inds, Unitize[inds[[All, 4]]], 0][[All, ;; 3]];
   quads =
    Pick[inds, Unitize[inds[[All, 4]]], 1];
   els =
    {
     If[Length[#] > 0, TriangleElement[#], Nothing] &@tris,
     If[Length[#] > 0, QuadElement[#], Nothing] &@quads
     };
   ElementMesh[
     "Coordinates" -> Flatten[grid, 1],
     "MeshElements" -> els
    ]
   ];
getRectMeshInds =
  Compile[
   {{dims, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[
    {
     totalDims = 0,
     bufferPos = 1,
     minElements = Total@Most[dims],
     bufferSize = 10000,
     randomShiz,
     cur,
     nextRow,
     nextUneq,
     nextDim,
     rowDim
     },
    randomShiz =
     (* initialize the quad element array *)
     Table[
      {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {i, 
       minElements + bufferSize(* 
       this is buffered because I can overflow but I didn't want to \
calculate by how much... *)
       }
      ];
    Do[
     rowDim = dims[[n]];
     nextDim = dims[[n + 1]];
     nextRow = totalDims + rowDim;
     nextUneq = nextDim != rowDim;
     Do[
      cur = totalDims + i;
      If[nextUneq || i < rowDim,
       Which[
        nextDim > i && i < rowDim,
        randomShiz[[cur]] =
         {
          cur, nextRow + i, 
          nextRow + i + 1, cur + 1
          },
        nextDim > i,
        Do[
         If[j == 0,
          randomShiz[[cur]] =
           {
            cur,  nextRow + i,
            nextRow + i + 1, 0
            },
          randomShiz[[minElements + bufferPos]] =
           {
            cur,  nextRow + i + j,
            nextRow + i + j + 1, 0
            };
          bufferPos++
          ],
         {j, 0, nextDim - i - 1}
         ],
        nextDim < i,
        randomShiz[[cur]] =
         {
          cur - 1,  cur,
          nextRow + nextDim, 0
          }
        ]
       ],
      {i, rowDim}
      ];
     totalDims = nextRow;,
     {n, Length[dims] - 1}
     ];
    Select[randomShiz, #[[1]] =!= 0 &]
    ],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

But this fails...

```
mesh2 = getRectMesh[myGrid];
Head[mesh2["Wireframe"]] === mesh2

True
```

I'm imagining that's because I have a mixture of `QuadElements` and `TriangleElements` but I don't know... just for reference here's the mesh I'm picturing:

```
GraphicsComplex[
  mesh2[[1, 2]],
  {
   EdgeForm[Black],
   {Red, Polygon /@ Apply[List, mesh2[[2, 2, 1]]]},
   {Blue, Polygon /@ Apply[List, mesh2[[2, 2, 2]]]},
   {Green, Point@Range[Length@mesh2[[1, 2]]]}
   }
  ] // Graphics
```

[image]

Can I make this work?

Mostly I'm just curious, but the overall goal was to use this in `ElementMeshInterpolation`, for which I could of course just use `ToElementMesh`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to mix `TriangleElement` and `QuadElement` in `ElementMesh`, see examples in [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshVisualization.html) tutorial.

Comment: Aha, you have a typo in `getRectMesh` function, you should call `ToElementMesh` instead of `ElementMesh`. And I think there is some problem with element node ordering.

Comment: @Pinti Ah I'm an idiot... Thanks for that. Any idea what the node-ordering issue could be? The wireframe looks clean.

Comment: Regarding the node ordering , check `mesh["Quality"]` to see which elements have negative quality and need to be reordered. Then reorder the element incidents in counterclockwise direction (see "Details" section in documentation for `TriangleElement`).